# Laravel reducing queries and understanding appends

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 models, `Category`, `Description` and `Expense`.

Each Category `hasMany` Descriptions and a Description `belongsTo` a Category, and each Description `hasMany` Expenses, and each Expense `belongsTo` a Description.

Now I have a simple `categories.index` page to display all categories. But for each category being displayed, I want to show a sum of all expenses for that category. I have a `hasManyThrough` relation like this:

Category Model:

```
public function expenses()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Expense::class, Description::class);
}
```

Now in my view I can do the following:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->expenses()->sum('amount')
@endforeach
```

Here is my first question. In my controller I am eager loading the descriptions and expenses:

```
$categories = auth()->user()->categories()
        ->with('descriptions')
        ->with('expenses')
        ->get());
```

Does this mean that I am not creating extra queries with how my view currently is setup? I think it does, which is bad, but I am unsure, just trying to understand it. And my second question in regards to this:

I tried adding this in my Category model, but it didn't add anything to my Category Objects:

```
protected $appends = ['expenses'];

public function getExpensesAttribute()
{
    return $this->expenses()->sum('amount');
}
```

It just showed this:

```
    #attributes: array:7 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "user_id" => 1
      "name" => "My Category"
      "slug" => "my-category"
      "created_at" => "2018-07-10 18:45:46"
      "updated_at" => "2018-07-10 18:45:46"
    ]
```

I think I am using it wrong / not understanding it. Any explanation on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appends aren't added to the internal attributes, but if you use `toArray()` or send a JSON response of the object, you should see them.  You wouldn't want them added to attributes since attributes are used to update the model in the database and you wouldn't have an expenses column.

---

**Warning:** You should not name your mutator expenses since this will conflict with your expenses relationship.

---

Eager loading the relationship won't do anything in this instance since you're querying the relation in your mutator instead of accessing the existing relationship collection.

If you're planning to always eager load expenses, then you should change

`$this->expenses()->sum('amount');`

to

`$this->expenses->sum('amount');`.

Accessing expenses as a property instead of a method which will use the loaded collection of expenses and sum the amount in PHP rather than reaching out to the database again.

Comment: Awesome answer, and I even knew about the `toArray` or JSON response, since I already looked this up last week. I just forgot, so thanks. And good to learn about the other stuff, too!